# Wait for Fragment transaction to happen before taking an action

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, transactions

I have used a fragment as a slider menu and have list view in it.
The fragment has a slide in and out animation.
OnClick of the item in listview I open an activity. Here the problem I face is when I start the activity . The slider in the fragment is freezed half way sliding back and on finish of the activity that half slider completes its popupstack action and closes .Thus giving a glitch effect.

I want that the slider slides in on click of the item in the list view and then the activity starts such that when the activity closes the slider would have already completed its transaction of popupstack.

Is there any way where I can know when the transaction is completed and then I start my new activity.

starting of Slider fragment from my main fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, 0, 0,
                                R.anim.exit_to_left)
                        .add(R.id.parent, new SliderMenuFragment())
                        .addToBackStack("animation").commit();
```

Slider fragment onclick event of Listview item

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("Home")) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        Intent homePage = new Intent(getActivity(),
                MyActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(homePage);

    }
```

MyActivity

finish() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done by overriding onCreateAnimator and adding animation listener so that you can start new activity from onAnimationEnd

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)
{
    final int animatorId = ... // get proper animation id
    final Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), animatorId);
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
        {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
           ...
        }
    });

    return anim;
```

}

Comment: In OnAnimationEnd  method the silder slides out but on clicking it again I use popbackstack which closes the slider , thus while closing the slider onAnimationEnd is not called. its called only when I beginTransaction